# What is an example of a proper normal subgroup of the kernel of a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, abstract-algebra

I'm reading this proof by Hungerford that concerns any normal subgroup of the kernel of a homomorphism.  I understand the proof well enough, but I wanted to have some concrete example to guide or ground my understanding, but I can't think of an example from among the symmetric groups, integers, rationals, or general or special linear groups that is small enough to be manageable and still can provide an example of such a thing.  Anyone have a suggestion?  I guess maybe I could take any group that has a normal subgroup and use the homomorphism that just maps everything to the identity, but then I feel like this wouldn't be easily generalized because then I'd want to add other elements to the domain, and at that point I wouldn't be sure that my normal subgroup was still normal in the new, bigger group.

Comment: That sounds a bit weird are you sure you aren't confusing notions? If what you write is precisely what you mean then any chain of normal subgroups $N \unlhd M \unlhd G$ provides an example because the homomorphism $\phi : G \to G/M$ has $N\unlhd M$ as a normal subgroup of the kernel. (e.g. $K_4 \unlhd \mathbf A_4 \unlhd \mathbf S_4$ for a non trivial example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z$ has $n\mathbb Z$ as the kernel, which has any $m\mathbb Z$ as a normal subgroup when $n\mid m$.